# CSS/HTML - make text go around an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image on a webpage and I would like the text to start right next to where the image does but go around the image, if the text length goes past the image, the text would go underneath the image... Like you would if in Microsoft Word you made an image "tight" and placed it in a paragraph. I am new to HTML and CSS... I've tried the `style = "display:inline"` but that does not seem to work. Can someone please help me?

My HTML (edited out the image URL):

```
<body>
    <div class = "main">
        <div class ="picture">
            <img src = "..." alt = "picture" style="width:180px;height:240px">
        <p style='display:inline;'>This is the <b>HOME</b> page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

My CSS:

```
    body {
    }

    .main {
    }
    .main .picture {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 5px;

        text-align: left;
    }
    .main .info{
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to add float: left to your image properties :

```
 body {
    }

    .main {
    }
    .main .picture {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .main .info{
    }

    .main img {
        float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u29yk98r/1/

Answer (score 3):

I think what your searching for is `float: left;`.
This sets the any element to ither the right or the left side.

Is this what your looking for?

```css
.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, lorem ipsum dollar si amet, lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,lorem ipsum dollar si amet,</span>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html><head><style>

 body {
    }

    .main {
    }
    .main .picture {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        float:left;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .main .info{
    }
</style>

</head><body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="..." alt="picture" style="width:180px;height:240px">
        <p style="display:inline;float: right;width: 500px;">This is the <b>HOME</b> page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body></html>
```

Hope this resolves your problem